# Python PyPi setup.py Не загружаются файлы библиотеки

Tags: python, библиотеки, library, setup, pypi

Есть небольшой модуль, который нужно загрузить на pypi.
Предварительно конечно же нужно сделать файл setup.py, на основании которого будет производится сборка модуля. Итак после сборки командой`python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` получаются 3 файла: .whl, .tar.gz, .win32.zip. И в них отсутствуют файлы самой библиотеки (**init**.py, main.py и т.д. и т.п.). Привожу дерево архива

archive
-lib-1.0.1 (dir)

--lib.egg-info (dir)

---top_level.txt (file)

---SOURCES.txt (file)

---requires.txt (file)

---PKG-INFO (file)

---depensy_links.txt (file)

--setup.cfg (file)

--setup.py (file)

Итак файлов библиотеки, а как я думаю они должны быть в папке lib-1.0.1, нет.
Её файлы по отношению к setup.py лежат в отдельной папке. Делал вроде всё, как в интернете.
**Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так. Буду благодарен за помощь.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, ваши файлы библиотеки не попадают в архив, так как не прописаны в файле setup.py. В этом файле вы можете указать, какие файлы должны быть включены в сборку модуля.

Например, это может выглядеть так:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
      name='lib',
      version='1.0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
     )
```

В этом примере `find_packages` ищет все пакеты в текущем каталоге и включает их в сборку модуля. Опция `include_package_data` указывает, что должны быть включены дополнительные файлы (например, init.py, main.py и т.д.).

Попробуйте использовать этот пример, и ваши файлы библиотеки должны появиться в архиве.

Надеюсь этот небольшой solution поможет)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё получилось